# I'm trying to write an excel formula for defining top values based on another data point, and I have exhausted my trial and error options

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I've got a list of 100k account numbers, and I've ranked the accounts based on some criteria.  The rank is in column D, and the lower the rank, the more important.  I also have the "owner" of the account in column B.  What I am looking to do is determine if the account in a row is in the top 5 accounts for the person in column B.  So I need define if the account on the row, for the the owner in column B, is one of the five lowest ranks for that specific owner.

[Truncated data set example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WHILh.png)

Answer (score 0):

Here you go

```
=IF((COUNTIFS(B:B,B2,D:D,"<"&D2)+1)<6,1,0)
```

Based on [this](https://exceljet.net/formula/rank-if-formula)

Comment: You, sir, are a peach.  Thank you so much.